# How to read Custom template from SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, pnp-powershell, document-template

I want read all custom document template and content type template which is used across site collection and sub site level using powershell. can someone suggest?

Causing the multiple entries in CSV:

```
$List = $web.Lists
$ctx.Load($List)
#$ctx.Load($List.ContentTypes)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$ResultCollection = @()
foreach($CT in $List)
  {
        
 
        $ctx.Load($CT.ContentTypes)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        
        
        foreach($cc in $CT.ContentTypes)
        {
        #Write-Host $cc.Name
        #Write-Host $cc.DocumentTemplate
       # Write-Host $cc.DocumentTemplateUrl
       # Write-Host $cc.Description 
        #Write-Host $cc.Group  
       # Write-Host $cc.Id
        #Write-Host $cc.Parent
        

$Result = New-Object PSObject


                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "SourceURL" -value $Url
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "WebURL" -value $Subweb.Url
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "ContentTypeName" -value $cc.Name
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "CTDocumentTemplate" -value $cc.DocumentTemplate
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "CTDocumentTemplateUrl" -value $cc.DocumentTemplateUrl
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "CTGroup" -value $cc.Group 
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "CTDescription" -value $cc.Description
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "ContentTypeID" -value $cc.Id
                        $Result | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "CTParentType" -value $cc.Parent
                        
                        $ResultCollection+=$Result;
  
     }
     #$FileName = $SiteCollectionName + "_DocuTemplateInfo"
     $ResultCollection | Export-Csv -path "C:\UserData\z00476kp\Documents\ExportItems\CTTemplateInfo_Modified.csv" -Append -Encoding UTF8  -notypeinformation
                     
        
        
     }Write-Host "CSV Exported"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below PowerShell script and which can be extended for your needs:

```
# Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer.
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
# Insert the credentials and the name of the admin site
$Username="admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$AdminPassword=Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString
$AdminUrl="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsitewithlibraries/sub Jump "

$ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)

$ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Lists)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach( $ll in $ctx.Web.Lists)
  {
 
        $ctx.Load($ll.ContentTypes)
 
        try
        {
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        catch
        {
        }

 Write-Host $ll.Title -ForegroundColor Green
        
        foreach($cc in $ll.ContentTypes)
     {
        Write-Output $cc.Name

       Now, here using the $cc property you can get the document template name associated with the particular content type......extend your code here. 
     }
 
}
```

Note:

- In the above content type for-each loop collection, using the $cc
  property you can get the document template name associated with the
  particular content type......extend your code there.

Reference Article:

[SharePoint Online content types in Powershell: Get](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31151.sharepoint-online-content-types-in-powershell-get.aspx)

Comment: This working!! thanks..

Comment: I have one query here this is for content type level. If i want from library document level..

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you... for library the logic is same... while you are looping through document library collection, inside the foreach loop of the document library, using the document library object, we can get document template for library as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!! you saved my day.. it is working as expected

Comment: one more question this document template i am reading site collection level . But i want to read it subsite level recursively..  how can i add

Comment: It is same as a document library and content type looping - put all existing code inside for each loop of all webs (this is all web collection) - use this example for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604076/use-powershell-to-retrieve-all-subsites-for-sharepoint-online

Comment: Actually Exporting the $cc.Name in CSV which is creating N number of duplicate entries. How can i reduce the duplicate entry

Comment: SPM  please check above section added the code